# Openssl command not working in Dockerfile Run

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker. I'm trying to work through some basic operations to increase my understanding. I have a very basic webapp that I've created and wanted to create a Dockerfile for it. One thing I would like to do is to have the webapp delivered over https. I would like to use Let's Encrypt. As I was just getting started, I found on Let's Encrypt's website, [instructions](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/#making-and-trusting-your-own-certificates) for creating a cert for local development.

I wanted to include that as a part of my Dockerfile.

I add the following to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN openssl req \
-x509 \
-out localhost.crt \
-keyout localhost.key \
-newkey rsa:2048 \
-nodes \
-sha256 \
-subj "/CN=localhost" \
-extensions EXT \
-config <(printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

Whenever I run the `docker build` command on this file though, I'm receiving the following error.

```
Step 12/18 : RUN openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -subj "/CN=localhost" -extensions EXT -config <(printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
 ---> Running in 079b3085beba
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
The command '/bin/sh -c openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -subj "/CN=localhost" -extensions EXT -config <(printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

As my simple application is a dotnet application, the base image is `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1`. This is an image built upon `3.1.4-buster-slim` which is a debian container.

I then ran `docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1` so that I could have shell access on that root container and I was able to then copy and paste the above command into the terminal and it worked just fine.

I'm running Docker for Windows on my Windows machine, so I thought perhaps I was getting the error due to the different line endings between Windows and Linux. I made sure all the line endings on the Dockerfile were `LF` and not `CRLF` and am still getting the same error. The Dockerfile is `UTF-8` encoding, which as far as I can tell is the standard for Linux as well.

I'm at a loss as to why I'm getting this error. What do I need to change about the command or the dockerfile to get the above command to work properly as a part of my Dockerfile build?

Comment: I suspect `/bin/sh` from `buster-slim` to not be compatible with Bash. You might need to adapt your command syntax to the installed shell (or install Bash/use an image with Bash to run your command with that syntax)

Comment: It probably is a `dash` shell, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310500/how-to-emulate-process-substitution-in-dash for possible syntax alternative

Comment: @michaeldel Thanks for those links. If what you are saying is true, then why did the same exact command work when I ran the container with `-it`? Is that running a bash command on the container?

Comment: Also, being new to linux, the links don't really help me understand what changes I need to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @[michaeldel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1812262/michaeldel) I was able to understand what problem was occurring.

After doing some searching, I found that in one's Dockerfile, the shell to be used can be specified. I updated my Dockerfile to the following and all is working now.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN echo "$(openssl version)"
RUN openssl req \
-x509 \
-out localhost.crt \
-keyout localhost.key \
-newkey rsa:2048 \
-nodes \
-sha256 \
-subj "/CN=localhost" \
-extensions EXT \
-config <(printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```